# Inserting into table depending on conditions

Tags: sql-server, insert

I'm trying to insert data into table but depending on the content it is supposed to be done different ways. My question is whether there exists such function that will work like follows:

```
WHEN Condition1 THEN INSERT INTO data1 SELECT * FROM table1

WHEN Condition2 THEN INSERT INTO data2 SELECT * FROM table2

...

ELSE SELECT 'done'
```

Comment: What type of conditions are you trying to evaluate? Are you evaluating based off of data that already exists, what is being passed, etc.?

Comment: Conditions are the results of a query. Let's say that if a query returns no records I need to do one thing and if it returns some, another thing.

Comment: It's still not terribly clear what you're trying to do. If you haven't executed `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, you can do an `INSERT` from `Table1`, check if any rows were affected, and do an `INSERT` from `Table2` if none were affected. However, I can't tell if that would actually help you or not....

Comment: But what if I don't want to check it if any rows are affected?

Comment: never ask half question,it will harm you.There many ways to achieve so depending upon exact requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [IF...ELSE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), ther is the complete example below:

```
declare @conditional_table table(col int);
insert @conditional_table values(1), (3), (4); 

declare @data1 table(col varchar(100));
declare @data2 table(col varchar(100));

declare @table1 table(col varchar(100));
insert @table1 values('table1');
declare @table2 table(col varchar(100));
insert @table2 values('table2');

declare @cnt int = 0;
--WHEN Condition1 THEN INSERT INTO data1 SELECT * FROM table1
-- let's say Condition1 is "there is 1 in @conditional_table"
if exists(select * from @conditional_table where col = 1)
begin
    insert into @data1 select * from @table1; 
    set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;

--WHEN Condition2 THEN INSERT INTO data2 SELECT * FROM table2
-- let's say Condition1 is "there is 2 in @conditional_table"
if exists(select * from @conditional_table where col = 2)
begin
    insert into @data2 select * from @table2;
    set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;

--ELSE SELECT 'done'
if @cnt = 0 
select 'done';

-------------------------
-- there was no 'done' selected because @count > 1, some conditions were true
select * from @data1; -- condition1 was true, 'table1' will be returned
select * from @data2; -- condition2 was false, no data is returned
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. The general formula of sth that works as case in c++, which can be applied to different conditions